# List item field hidden from Edit form

Tags: content-type, splistitem, edit-form

I have a content-type consisting of two columns: `Title` and `Description`.

- `Title` is required and a single line of text
- `Description` is optional and consists of more lines of text (Rich text editor).

When creating a new item from this content-type, both fields are shown and everything works as intended, but if I want to edit the item, the `Description` field isn't showing. The `Description` field is not hidden.

On the following images, the language is Danish.

- `Titel` = Title
- `Beskrivelse` = Description
- `Gem` = Save

**When creating the item**
[image]

**When editing the item**
[image]

Comment: Using development in c# or powershell you can hide fields conditionally in diferent forms. Is it possible than somebody made some development on this site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit form is a custom form...which is being customized not to include Description column in Edit form. How about Display form..there do u see any description field?

Open the forms in Designer and create a new edit form and set it as default. you will be able to view all fields in edit form.

Comment: I do see the `Description` field in the Display form

Comment: Edit form has been customized. Please provide the last part of the Edit page URL...is it something like this: .../EditForm.aspx

Comment: It was the `EditForm.aspx` that was messed up. I eventually found the problem. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the forms in SharePoint Designer and take a look which one is set to default for the edit form.

If you don't have access to SPD please check the URL of the editform. The normal one is `/EditForm.aspx`

The first steps how to customize your forms is shown here:

https://afrait.com/blog/custom-new-edit-or-display-form-in-4-steps-en/